# How to trigger button click through selenium webdriver if only class name is available

Tags: selenium, button, checkbox

I am writing a python using the selenium webdriver to simulate the button click and select a checkbox.  However, it was failed.  Please kindly advise how to perform the button click for "Search Again", then select the checkbox of "Ensuite" and then press the button "Apply Filter".
See below code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
web = webdriver.Chrome()
url ="https://www.spareroom.co.uk/flatshare/search.pl"
web.get(url)
# page 1
web.find_element(By.ID, "search_by_location_field").clear()
web.find_element(By.ID, "search_by_location_field").send_keys("SW5")
web.find_element(By.ID,"onetrust-accept-btn-handler").click()
web.find_element(By.ID,"search-button").click()
# page 2
# to press the button "Search Again"
# to select the checkbox "Ensuite"
# to press the button "Apply filters"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url = 'https://www.spareroom.co.uk/flatshare/search.p'
wait = WebDriverWait(web, 20)
web.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.panel-tab > a:nth-child(2)'))).click()

web.find_element(By.ID, "search_by_location_field").clear()
web.find_element(By.ID, "search_by_location_field").send_keys("SW5")
web.find_element(By.ID,"search-button").click()
```

First wait for the accept button to pop up. Click advanced tab and then find element.

Import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks Arudeep.   After executing the code, it goes to the result page.    Then I try to build a code to press the "Search Again" button, then select the option "Ensuite" and press the "Apply filters".  But I all fail.   Do you know how to resolve it?

Comment: I have resolved my problem in another post. 
Thanks  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72757365/element-div-class-form-group-checkbox-div-is-not-clickable-at-point-3

Comment: @goodfit - Please upvote or accept the answer if answer have solved your issue, even from the other question, this will help others. thanks

Comment: @Akzy  Is there any button to press or simply make a comment?